# Link and include script

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

I have this page with a include script that is:

```
<script> 
    $(function(){
        $("#header").load("header.html"); 
    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly on my computer but on the webserver it stops working, I've tried `header.html` , `./header.html` and `//header.html`. 
 Other links, for images for exemple, work perfectly. Help?

Comment: `.load("/header.html")` should work if your `header.html` file is in the root directory. Where is it located ?

Comment: it's in the same folder as the file containing this include. Not on the public_htlml root but on another folder inside it.

Comment: So try using: `$("#header").load("/foldername/header.html");`

Comment: Didn't work... here's a link for the website http://ocupart.pt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examining your website, you have an error in your JQuery which **prevents your JQuery code from working**. Fix the following issues:

[image]

After that, Try loading your HTML file with a full path starting from the root directory :

```
$("#header").load("/foldername/header.html");
```

Comment: thank you so much? How could I see a debug like that? I had not uploaded jquery which was dumb, I have done it now but it's still not working. Maybe if I can see the debug now I can solve it

Comment: Open the page in Chrome > Click F12 > Look at the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try Giving the absolute path for the "header.html" file.
For Ex - "C:/users/wamp/html/header.html"

Comment: This is incorrect. You should never use `C:` paths.

Comment: uncorrect ? I just gave an example for specifying absolute path , if running on windows wamp server as I have configured my system.It may be hosted on linux or somewhere ...Its up to the one who asked the question.